# Comparing values doesn't seem to be working (possible obvious answer)

Tags: objective-c, comparator

My code is:

```
float arrayCount = [_bodyArray count];           //counts array
number = [self getUserNumber];                  //get user method
float counter = arrayCount/number;             //division (in this case 1/3)

NSLog(@"counter= %f", counter);
NSLog(@"Chestcount = %lu", [_bodyArray count]);
NSLog(@"number= %lu", (long)number);

if (counter == 0)  {
    _yellow.alpha=0;
    _orange.alpha=0;
    _red.alpha=0;

} else if (counter <= 0.25f){
    _yellow.alpha = 1;
    _orange.alpha = 0;
    _red.alpha = 0;

} else if (0.26f < counter <= 0.50f){               //Where it should be stopping
    _yellow.alpha = 0;
    _orange.alpha = 1;
    _red.alpha = 0;

}
else {                                          //Where it stops instead
    _yellow.alpha = 0;
    _orange.alpha = 0;
    _red.alpha = 1;
    NSLog(@"counter= %f", counter);         //This outprints 0.333333
}
```

I have an app that needs to compare values and depending on which, change the value of alpha for that particular image. Problem being it will always use the else function, my NSLog returns a value  of 0.33333 for "count", but it doesn't recognize the value for some reason.

If I change the last else statement and add an if condition (counter >= 0.51) the images simply don't change values. It isn't correctly comparing the values for some reason, I apologize if i'm over looking something simple but i've been trying to figure it out for a couple days now and I can't make sense of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
else if (0.26f < counter && counter <= 0.50f)
```

**anyway improving a little bit your code**

```
_yellow.alpha=0;
_orange.alpha=0;
_red.alpha=0;

if (counter <= 0.25f){
    _yellow.alpha = 1;
} else if (0.26f < counter && counter <= 0.50f){               //Where it should be stopping
    _orange.alpha = 1;
}else {                                          //Where it stops instead
    _red.alpha = 1;
    NSLog(@"counter= %f", counter);         //This outprints 0.333333
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That did it! Can't believe I didn't try this. Thank you!!

Comment: @tysco check my updated answer and let me know if works as should be

Comment: much cleaner and works perfect, (just forgot to add your own correction in the edited answer) but much appreciated!